# Need some help accessing JSON Data iPhone

Tags: iphone, json, syntax

Disclaimer: I'm new to JSON.

I have a website that offers up it's Data in JSON format and I'm in the process of building an iPhone App to access that data. The problem I have is not actually with the app itself but rather the syntax to access some of the JSON data.

I don't have any issue accessing the data in the **Post [ ]** Section, however I want to access **Attachments > Images > wptouch-new-thumbnail > url**

I know you usually would access the data with a dot syntax but with everything I have tried I have been unable to select anything outside of the Post[] section.

it's pretty simple I take what I get from the server through posts and add them to NSStrings or UIImage in the case of the images for use in a UITableView.

I have all of that working however I can't seem to access anything under attachments. I tried to make a different NSDictionary for attachments but that did not work.

Again remember I'm very new to JSON / Accessing data within it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make `NSMutableData` as `jsonMutableData` instead of NSMutableString.
in connection `dedreceiveresponse`, initialize `jsonMutableData` then,

```
 //Json Connection

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [jsonMutableData appendData:partialData];   
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{

    NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonMutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   

    NSDictionary *filesJSON = [jsonData JSONValue];


    NSArray *files = [filesJSON objectForKey:@"posts"];
//further code
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how will changing it to NSMutableData instead of NSMutableString help me to get the information in "attachments" ? if I change it do I just ** NSString *wpimage = [file objectForKey:@"wptouch-new-thumbnail"];


        [wptouch addObject: wpimage]; ** and it will work?

Comment: it is not about changing NSMutableString to NSMutableData. see the "key" thing is you have to wait until all the data is received completely before trying it to convert it to NSString as there might be the case where your data is not completely received in first chunk. that's what has been shown in the code I posted.